# v16.6.0 or higher Context API not working when child is used in component that provides the context

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context, tsx

I'am using the new context API of react (v16.6.0 or higher) by declaring the `public static contextType` inside the component that consumes the context.
This is working fine as long as the component that declares the `Provider` does not directly use a component that consumes the context in it's `render()` method.

**Example:**

**ParentWithContext**

This is the component that creates and provides the context.

```
export const SomeContext = React.createContext({
  someValue: false
});

export default class ParentWithContext extends Component {
  public render(){
    const contextValue = {someValue: true};
    return (
      <SomeContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
        <ChildOne />
        {this.props.children}
      </SomeContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Notice that this component uses `ChildOne` component (s. right below) in it's `render()` method.

**ChildOne** and **ChildTwo**

These two components simply consume the above context and display it.

```
export default class ChildOne extends Component {
  public static contextType = SomeContext;
  public render(){
    return (
      <div>
        {`Context of ChildOne: ${this.context.someValue}`}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default class ChildTwo extends Component {
  public static contextType = SomeContext;
  public render(){
    return (
      <div>
        {`Context of ChildTwo: ${this.context.someValue}`}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**index.tsx**

```
class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <ParentWithContext>
        <ChildTwo />
        <ChildOne />
      </ParentWithContext>
    );
  }
}
```

Running this example will produce following lines:

```
Context of ChildOne: undefined
Context of ChildTwo: true
Context of ChildOne: undefined
```

So `ChildTwo` seems to receive the correct information from `this.context`, while `ChildOne` receives nothing.

Now comes the weird part (to me): When you remove the `<ChildOne/>` from `ParentWithContext` it suddenly works for both `ChildOne` and `ChildTwo`

**New ParentWithContext**

```
export default class ParentWithContext extends Component {
  public render(){
    const contextValue = {someValue: true};
    return (
      <SomeContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
        {this.props.children}
      </SomeContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

**New HTML output**

```
Context of ChildTwo: true
Context of ChildOne: true
```

[Running Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-8pdvte?file=index.tsx)

**Question**

Why is the context API (>=v16.6) not working (using `static contextType`) when the `Provider` component directly uses a child component that consumes the context in it's `render()` function? Is this a bug or a known limitation? Did I miss something?

**Additonal information**

Using `<SomeContext.Consumer>` will work as expected.

```
export default class ChildOne extends Component {
  public render(){
    return (
      <SomeContext.Consumer>
        {context =>
          <div>
          {`Context of ChildOne: ${context.someValue}`}
          </div>
        }
      </SomeContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
}
```

Of course  it's not a solution for this issue but might be a useful information.

Comment: I'd say it's a bug. Consider reporting it.

Comment: @estus I will if no one provides a solution in the next few hours/days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was creating an [issue on reacts github](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14530#issuecomment-451587644) to find out that it was not a react bug but a Javascript/Typescript issue.

**Summary**

Wrong import ordering caused the "bug". Because `ChildOne` was imported (in `ParentWithContext`) before the declartion of the context, `SomeContext` was actually `undefined` when it was imported in `ChildOne`.

```
import ChildOne from "./ChildOne";

export const SomeContext = React.createContext({
  someValue: false
});
```

So one solution would be to exhcange those two statemants

```
export const SomeContext = React.createContext({
  someValue: false
});

import ChildOne from "./ChildOne";
```

Or simply (and IMHO cleaner) extract the context into it's own file.
That way you exclude any similiar issues in the future.